Can't use Emulator on Chromebook
I'm having trouble getting my Chromebook to work. It seems that every application I install is not working on this Emulator ( violation Code: 4
Tried using the test application on my phone works perfectly fine but on Chromebooks it's a pain.
Tried power washing/Using developer mode/Removed the enterprise edition. Still doesn't work.
After doing all these worst is that my Chromebook applications aren't usable anymore.
Any suggestion to make this work or fix the issue?
Tried using the test application on my phone works perfectly fine but on Chromebooks it's a pain. Tried power washing/Using developer mode/Removed the enterprise edition. Still doesn't work.

Did you install the Linux integration?
